# Help clean up the Mac Office tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Office for Mac uses versions like 2008 and 2011, which makes it different from Office for Windows (2003, 2007, 2010).

The [word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word) tag wiki suggests that for Mac there should be:

- [word-2004](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word-2004)
- [word-2008](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word-2008)
- [word-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word-2011)

… but neither of those has a question tagged.

Also, [microsoft-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office) does not even mention the Office for Mac tags.

---

So, we need to do the following:

- Find all the questions that are about Office for Mac, and retag them accordingly (e.g. [office-2008](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2008) and [office-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2011). I just couldn't find them. Are they buried somewhere in a combination of `[office]` and `[mac]`?

  Probably [something like this](https://superuser.com/questions/343952/excel-on-mac-doesnt-show-chinese-characters):

  [image]
- Somehow retag all the Word, Excel, etc. questions for Mac to use the same style of tags as their Windows counterparts (like the Word tags mentioned above).

Maybe I'm blind today, but I just couldn't find them, and my attempt to tag [a recent question about Word for Mac](https://superuser.com/q/343662/48078) was not very efficient.

Comment: this has been bugging me since the past few weeks, but I hadn't got the time to take a deeper look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Almost there!

This could be done by a moderator. I've looked over the posts, and these merges should be safe.

- <s>Merge [mac-outlook-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-outlook-2011) and [outlook-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/outlook-2011) into just [outlook-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/outlook-2011).</s> - **Completed**
- <s>Merge [anything tagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office+mac) [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac) and [microsoft-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office) into [office-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-for-mac). These are 30, and they seem fine. No damage done through merging. Remove the `mac` tag here, as it's hardware only and a common mistake in software-related questions.</s> - **Completed**
- <s>When the above is done: Merge [anything tagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx+microsoft-office) [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) and [microsoft-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office) into [office-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-for-mac). Keep the `osx` tag, it might be relevant.</s> - **Completed**

Once we're done with this, I'll look into the specific version combinations for our new [office-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-for-mac) tag and the single products like Word, Excel and PowerPoint. But that's another story!

Comment: I've done the first synonym and merge, however the second two will have to be done manually. We have no way of merging tags based on more then one tag via the admin tools. This will have to be done as a manual cleanup, unfortunately.