# Can I get a few Office for Mac synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

I finally [fixed our Office for Mac tags](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3550/help-clean-up-the-mac-officetags), and I managed to do it without a posse!

Now, the [office-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-for-mac) tag has 44 questions, and there are several subtags for the individual programs and Office versions. Feel free to check [the new tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/office-for-mac/info). Neat.

What I'd now suggest is **creating a few synonyms** so that the weird [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac) and [microsoft-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office) combinations don't pop up again.

I think those would be good to have:

- [office-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-for-mac) ← [mac-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-office) (since a lot of people say "Mac Office" too)
- [office-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-for-mac) ← [office-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-mac) (since Microsoft uses "office:mac" as a short name as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Tag synonyms have been created and approved. [Newest and Active Synonyms](https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?filter=active&tab=newest)